# Optimizing away static variable / passing by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, compiler-optimization, static-variables

In this question [Will a static variable always use up memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7755257/8052809) it is stated that compilers are allowed to optimize away a static variable if the address is never taken, e.g. like following:

```cpp
void f() {
   static int i = 3;
   printf( "%d", i );
}
```

1. If there exists a function which takes its arguments by reference, is the compiler still allowed to optimize away the variable, e.g. as in

```cpp
void ref( int & i ) {
    printf( "%d", i );
}
void f() {
   static int i = 3;
   g( i );
}
```

2. Is the situation different for the "perfect forwarding" case. Here the function body is empty on purpose:

```cpp
template< typename T >
void fwd( T && i ) {
}
void f() {
   static int i = 3;
   fwd( i );
}
```

3. Furthermore, would the compiler be allowed to optimize the call in the following case. (The function body is empty on purpose again):

```cpp
void ptr( int * i ) {
}
void f() {
   static int i = 3;
   ptr( &i );
}
```

My questions arise from the fact, that references are not a pointer by the standard - but implemented as one usually.

**Apart from, *"is the compiler allowed to?"* I am actually more interested in whether compilers do this kind of optimization?**

Comment: Most functions are compiled/optimized in isolation, so I would doubt that it would get optimized away when you start passing it to other functions.  That said, there is now link time optimization, and I'm not sure if this is something that could be optimized away during LTO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> that compilers are allowed to optimize away a static variable if the address is never taken

You seem to concentrated on the wrong part of the answer. The answer states:

> the compiler can do anything it wants to your code so long as the observable behavior is the same

The end. You can take the address, don't take it, calculate the meaning of life and calculate how to heal cancer, the *only* thing that matters is observable effect. As long as you don't actually heal cancer (or output the results of calculations...), all calculations are just no-op.

> f there exists a function which takes its arguments by reference, is the compiler still allowed to optimize away the variable

Yes. The code is just `putc('3')`.

> Is the situation different for the "perfect forwarding" case

No. The code is still just `putc('3')`.

> would the compiler be allowed to optimize the call in the following case

Yes. This code has no observable effect, contrary to the previous ones. The call to `f()` can just be removed.

> in whether compilers do this kind of optimization?

Copy your code to https://godbolt.org/ and inspect the assembly code. Even with no experience in assembly code, you will see differences with different code and compilers.

Choose `x86 gcc (trunk)` and remember to enable optimizations `-O`. Copy code with `static`, then remove `static` - did the code change? Repeat for all code snippets.

Comment: On godbolt I only see the assembly, I do not see (or at least I dont know how) whether there is a static variable allocated somewhere.

Comment: Sure - so remove `static`. Did the code change? Also you'll see - for example: https://godbolt.org/z/fzq318Tx3 - there's `i.0:` label, it's the variable `i`. It's initialized with `long 3`.

Comment: Oh, thats great. Such a long question, and such a simple answer - Godbolt is amazing.

Comment: @tommsch: Give your `static` variable a longer unique name so you can find it in the compiler's asm output without even having to diff.  Like `xyz` won't naturally occur anywhere in GCC's asm output.  Also, make sure you use `-O2`; just plain `-O` (`-O1`) might not enable function inlining and/or enough inter-procedural analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers are allowed to optimize out variables under the "as-if" rule, meaning that the compiler is allowed to do any optimization that doesn't alter the observable behaviour of the program. Whether the optimization actually occurs depends on how good the compiler's optimizer is, what optimization level you request, and whether the optimization belongs to a class of optimizations that actually improve performance (humans are not very good at predicting this).

In all of the examples you gave, the as-if rule gives the compiler latitude to eliminate the static variable.

In example 1, the definition of `f` is equivalent to `void f() { printf("%d", 3); }`. Since this has the exact same observable behaviour as the `f` you wrote, the compiler is allowed to replace one by the other, optimizing out the variable.

In example 2, since `fwd` does nothing, the definition of `f` is equivalent to `void f() {}`. Again, the as-if rule allows the compiler to replace the `f` you wrote with this empty function.

Example 3 is very similar to example 2 in terms of the implications of the as-if rule.

If you want to see whether a compiler will actually perform these optimizations, Godbolt is very useful. For example, if you look [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fTrW68nzz), you'll see that at `-O2`, both GCC and Clang will perform the optimization described for example 1. They probably do this by first inlining `ref` into `f`.

Comment: Part of the key to example 1 is that `void ref( int &i )` is defined in the same file, so the compiler can see its definition and inline it.  Otherwise it *would* be passing the address to code outside this compilation unit, which it has to assume might hold onto it.  But yes, after inlining, the address doesn't escape `f()`.